# How do you pause something in tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I have being trying to make a quiz in tkinter where after each round the correct question goes sreen to show it was correct and the other three go red then it goes on to the next round. My problem is that normal time delays like time.sleep() and root.after() don't solve the issue here and just pause it on the button pressed down (I have tried these in many different places). I was told that it will not work like this because the window only updates through the main loop of the program at the end and thus the colour change and moving on to the next round are clumped together so that it moves onto the next round before you can observe the colour change.I would really appreciate any help I could get with this.
Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.title("football quiz ")

class football_questions():
    def __init__(self,prompt,correct):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.correct = correct

question_prompts = [
    ["Which player scored the fastest hat-trick in the Premier League?","Sadio Mane","Jack Grealish"," Marcus Rashford","Tammy Abraham"],
    ["which football player has played for the most clubs","Rivaldo ","Nicolas Anelka","John Burridge"," Craig Bellamy"],
    ["who is the only player to be outright top for both goals scored and assists provided in a single Premier League season"," Peter Crouch","Craig Bellamy","Juninho Paulista","Andy Cole"],
    ["The fastest goal scored in Premier League history came in 7.69 seconds. Who scored it?","Lionel Messi","wayne rooney","Sergio Agüero","Shane Long"],
    ["Which Spanish club's nickname is Los Colchoneros, which translates to English as 'The Mattress Makers'?","Villarreal","Athletic Bilbao","Atletico Madrid","Real Sociedad"],
    ["Which German multinational sportswear company is Messi an ambassador for?","Adidas","2XU","Airness","Acerbis"],
    ["Which outfield player appeared in the Champions League final in three different decades?","Ryan Giggs","Gareth Bale","Daniele Massaro ","Cristiano Ronaldo"],
    ["Who is the only player to achieve 200 match wins in the premier league in under 300 matches", "Kevin De Bruyne","David Silva","Sergio Agüero","İlkay Gündoğan"],
    ["Which player has the highest number of penalties scored in the 21st century","Zlatan Ibrahimovic","Lionel Messi","Francesco Totti","Cristiano Ronaldo"],
    ["With 202 clean sheets, which goalkeeper has the best record in the Premier League?"," Joe Hart","Nigel Martyn","Petr Cech","David James"],
    ["Rangers tried to sign which superstar after Alex McLeish was alerted to his ability through popular video game Football Manager?","Lionel Messi","Cristiano Ronaldo","Sir Alex Ferguson","luis suarez"]
]

Q1 = football_questions((question_prompts[0])[0],1)
Q2 = football_questions((question_prompts[1])[0],3)
Q3 = football_questions((question_prompts[2])[0],4)
Q4 = football_questions((question_prompts[3])[0],4)
Q5 = football_questions((question_prompts[4])[0],3)
Q6 = football_questions((question_prompts[5])[0],1)
Q7 = football_questions((question_prompts[6])[0],1)
Q8 = football_questions((question_prompts[7])[0],2)
Q9 = football_questions((question_prompts[8])[0],4)
Q10 = football_questions((question_prompts[9])[0],3)
Q11 = football_questions((question_prompts[10])[0],1)

Qs = [Q1.prompt,Q2.prompt,Q3.prompt,Q4.prompt,Q5.prompt,Q6.prompt,Q7.prompt,Q8.prompt,Q9.prompt,Q10.prompt,Q11.prompt]
Qa = [Q1.correct,Q2.correct,Q3.correct,Q4.correct,Q5.correct,Q6.correct,Q7.correct,
      Q8.correct,Q9.correct,Q10.correct,Q11.correct]
score = 0
count = 0
x= 0
def recon ():
    my_label.config(text=Qs[x])
    option1.config(text=(question_prompts[x])[1], bg="SystemButtonFace", command=lambda: entry(1))
    option2.config(text=(question_prompts[x])[2], bg="SystemButtonFace", command=lambda: entry(2))
    option3.config(text=(question_prompts[x])[3], bg="SystemButtonFace", command=lambda: entry(3))
    option4.config(text=(question_prompts[x])[4], bg="SystemButtonFace", command=lambda: entry(4))

def entry(num):
   global score
   global x
   global count
   count +=1

   if Qa[x] == 1:
       option1.config(bg = "green")
       option2.config(bg = "red")
       option3.config(bg="red")
       option4.config(bg="red")
   elif Qa[x] == 2:
       option1.config(bg="red")
       option2.config(bg="green")
       option3.config(bg="red")
       option4.config(bg="red")

   elif Qa[x] == 3:
       option1.config(bg="red")
       option2.config(bg="red")
       option3.config(bg="green")
       option4.config(bg="red")
   elif Qa[x] == 4:
       option1.config(bg="red")
       option2.config(bg="red")
       option3.config(bg="red")
       option4.config(bg="green")
   if num == Qa[x]:
       score += 1
   time.sleep(2)
   x +=1
   if count <10:
       recon()

   else:
       End_score =Label(text = "Well done you scored" +" "+ str(score)+" " +"out of 11", font = 40)
       End_score.place(relx=0.5,rely =0.5,anchor = CENTER)
   print(x,score, count, Qa[x])


my_label = Label(text = Q1.prompt,font = 40)
my_label.place(relx=0.5,y= 20,anchor = CENTER)

empty_lable = Label().grid(column = 0, row = 1, rowspan = 4)
option1 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[1],padx = 20,pady = 20,width = 40,command = lambda: entry(1) )
option2 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[2],padx = 20,pady = 20,width = 40,command = lambda: entry(2) )
option3 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[3],width = 40,padx = 20,pady = 20,command = lambda: entry(3) )
option4 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[4],width = 40,padx = 20,pady = 20,command = lambda: entry(4) )

option1.place(x= 10, y =150, )
option2.place(x= 10, y =250, )
option3.place(x= 10, y =350, )
option4.place(x= 10, y =450, )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if You use `time.sleep` You can try calling `root.update()` before that tho not suggested, also I don't see You use `root.after()` at all. Also I suggest You create labels using loops so that you don't have to do everything manually. also it would maybe be a bit better to just use dictionaries instead of a list

Comment: Hi @Matiiss thanks for the  advice. Do you mean use labels like a colour overlay? nice idea. In regards to not using root. after() I have tried that and time.sleep() all over my code to see if it would change in different places , this posted version is just the most recent.

Comment: what `sleep()` does is freeze the whole script and in the case of tkinter labels can update only when they reach `.mainloop()` (or if `.update()` is called but again not suggested) so using sleep just prolongs the time taken to reach `.mainloop()` so they don't update until `sleep` finishes. One way would be to put `root.update()` and after that `time.sleep(seconds)` somewhere at the end so that way it will update and then wait so it should work, but probably the best way would be to do sth like: `root.after(3000, next_question)` or sth like that right after the colors change

Comment: Thanks @Matiiss that worked right away

Answer (score 0):

In order to freeze a program, you can use:

```py
timeDelayVar = None
def timeDelay(addTime):
    global timeDelayVar
    if timeDelayVar == None:
        timeDelayVar = int(time.time())
    if int(time.time() > int(timeDelayVar + addTime)):
        timeDelayVar = None
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and then in your program, you can use:

```py
while not timeDelay(2):
    try:
        root.mainwindow.update_idletasks()
        root.mainwindow.update()
    except:
        pass
```

This will add some delay without freezing the interface (It will still be updated)!